# How to display thumbnail in dropdown CSS list along with other styling of text

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've searched and came across a few examples but have been unable to merge them into my existing code, but I would prefer to keep the current styling and hover options if it is possible.

I have uploaded the menu code to http://jsfiddle.net/ob5fa8mg/

What I am wanting to do, is display a small image to the left of each menu item (image will be different for each item)  The image size will be 16px x 11px

HTML:

```
    <!--drop down menu start-->
    <div class="menu-wrap">
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Pages <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Page 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!--drop down menu end-->
```

CSS:

```
/* drop down menu */
 .clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
 .menu-wrap {
    background: #32271F;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-border-radius:.3em;
    -moz-border-radius:.3em;
    border-radius:.3em;
}
.menu {
    width:990px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color: #d9c8be;
}
.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}
/*----- Top Level -----*/
 .menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:19px;
    -webkit-border-radius:.3em;
    -moz-border-radius:.3em;
    border-radius:.3em;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background: #352a22;
    -webkit-border-radius:.3em;
    -moz-border-radius:.3em;
    border-radius:.3em;
}
/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
 .sub-menu {
    width:160%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: #352a22;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}
.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
}
.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background: #473a30;
}
}
/* drop down menu END */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some way to do this.

You can add a (for example span) in your a tag.

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="icon icon-page1"></span>
        Page 1
    </a>
</li>
```

and do rules like

```
.icon {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.icon.icon-page1 {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/16x16');
}
```

which will works and output like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ob5fa8mg/2/) show you.

Take note that if you can work with svg, it will be a better way to create a custom font with your icons and use it to display your icons (like font-awseome, glyphicons, ...)

Look [here](http://rafaltomal.com/how-to-create-and-use-your-own-icon-fonts/) for more information

Hope it's gonna help you.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I haven't coded in ages and it's been a struggle getting back into things, but I was able to modify it slightly using your example and it's absolutely perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image file, I would recommend doing something like this:

```
nav li a{
background-image: url('path/to/your/image.png');
background-size:16px 11px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left;
}
```

edit: removed trailing `

Comment: I found a similar solution but was wondering how this would work if I have a different image for each list item?   The solution above works great, but I'm sure there are more than one way of doing such.